# Input field on Chrome shows scrollbar

Tags: google-chrome, input, scrollbar

I have tried searching but was not able to locate the subject on this.

I am building simple 2 num inputs and one button form, but I have noticed that Chrome displays scrollbar on hover, focus, or active and I am not able to remove it

```
<input type="number" id="hValue" class="userValues" value="Enter Height" onfocus="this.value=''">
```

I have tried using CSS below, but still no effect:

overflow: hidden; 
resize: none;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to hide arrows from Input Number

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
 
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```